# Searching both document directory and main bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, nsstring

A uitableview (aqgridview) must display a title string based on the name of the document at a certain position in the grid.  The name obviously corresponds to the name of the file in either directory.  But my problem is that I defined a static NSString of 4 documents in my bundle, and I can easily get their titles.  But I want to get the names of the files contained in both my app bundle and of the documents directory. When I load my app with something from the documents directory, it just keeps repeating the 4 static string titles.  Code available on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `NSDirectoryEnumerator` together with the `NSFileManager` method `enumeratorAtPath` to get the filelists from the resource and the doc dir.